# List Image NonPadding

Tags: html, css

I made a gallery and user can upload to gallery in this photo. But photos don't show padding in background and giving this bad screen..

Image

[image]

```
 .fotograf
{
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fotograf ul li
{
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.fotograf ul li img
{
    display: block;
}
.maincenter
{
    background: url("img/maincenter.png") repeat;
    width: 926px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    padding-left: 55px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

I want to automatically resize this gallery background.

thank you.

Best Regards!

Comment: it would be useful to know the HTML structure

Comment: I tryed to <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> but doesnt work..

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.fotograf`

Answer (score 0):

Try add overflow, like:

```
.fotograf {
     display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

or float

```
.fotograf {
         float: left;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```